# consulta relacionando dos tablas no vinculadas

Tags: mysql

tengo una consulta sql que me lleva de cabeza,  tengo dos tablas no vinculadas entre si, de las cuales yo quiero seleccionar los usuarios cuyo año de nacimiento esté entre el año de inicio de la categoria y la año final. Estas son las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios (   
   id_usuario          int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
   use_nombre          varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL, 
   use_apellidos       varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL, 
   use_direccion       varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL, 
   use_codigo_postal   int(5) NULL, 
   use_telefono1       int(9) NULL, 
   use_telefono2       int(9) NULL, 
   Use_año_nacimiento int(11)  NULL,   /* esta es la referencia */
   Use_DNI varchar(9)  NULL,  /* -- dni con letra */   
   PRIMARY KEY (Id_usuario)    ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Consulta2:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categorias 
  ( 
     id_categoria          INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     id_modalidad          INT(11) NOT NULL, 
     nombre_categoria      VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE 
     utf8_unicode_ci       OT NULL, 
     año_inicio_categoria  INT(11) NULL, /* y estos son los campos que hay que utilizar para  el filtro */ 
     año_fin_categoria     int(11)  NULL 
     PRIMARY KEY (id_categoria) 
  ) 
engine=innodb DEFAULT charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci auto_increment=1;
```

Saludos

Comment: Estupendo... y con que consulta lo has intentado?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido Jose, sería necesario apra ayudarte que nos indiques qué has intentado.

Comment: No entiendo cuál es punto de la consulta "relacionada" si quieres datos de la tabla usuarios nada más. Simplemente haz un select sobre usuarios y pon las fechas del rango que buscas en el where.

Answer (score 1):

*A falta de mas información*, sugiero armar la siguiente consulta 
**(la cual no he probado:)**

```
SELECT usrs.use_nombre, usrs.use_apellidos, usrs.use_direccion, usrs.use_codigo_postal, usrs.Use_DNI
FROM usuarios AS usrs, categorias AS catgs
WHERE usrs.Use_año_nacimiento BETWEEN catgs.año_inicio_categoria AND catgs.año_fin_categoria
```

Answer (score -2):

Tendrás que crear un procedimiento almacenado, en el que te declares un cursos, del cual obtengas los años de las categorías, y luego lanzar esa consulta sobre la tabla usuarios

Comment: ¿Por qué un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: Y porque asumes que el volumen de los datos será tal como para dar un timeout? o como puedes saber en que maquina se ejecutará la consulta como para asumir aquello? __Asumir__ ... el peor error de un informático, además la respuesta a esta pregunta es una sencilla consulta SQL, no requiere SP ni triggers ni nada de eso :)